# How to check ensure a array does not contain the same element twice

Tags: java

I have a loop which assigns randomly generated integers into an array.
I need a way to ensure the same integer is not input into the array twice.

I figured creating a loop inside the overall loop would work but I am unsure on what to execute here.

```
int wwe[] = new int[9];
for(int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++){
    int randomIndex = generator.nextInt(wwe.length);
    wwe[i] = randomIndex;

    System.out.println(wwe[i]);
    System.out.println("########");
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
        System.out.println("This is the inner element " + wwe[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can print your array without an extra loop: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wwe));`

Comment: [Element Distinctness Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem)

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm to select n random but different elements from a set, or for an algorithm to check whether a random selection has only unique values?

Comment: I'm looking to ensure the same random value is not added twice to the array yet there should be 9 random values in the array.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to enforce unique values, use a data structure meant for such a behavior, like a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) or [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) would work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually looking for shuffling your array.

Note that what you really looking for is to find a random order of your array, this is called a [*permutation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation).

In java, it can be simply done using a list with **[`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)**.

If you are looking to implement it on your own - use [**fisher yates shuffle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), it is fairly easy to implement.

Since other answers showed how to do it with Collections.shuffle() already - here is a simple implementation + example of fisher yates shuffle, that does not need to convert the original array into a list.

```
private static void swap (int[] arr, int i1, int i2) {
    int temp = arr[i1];
    arr[i1] = arr[i2];
    arr[i2] = temp;
}
private static void shuffle(int[] arr, Random r) { 
    for (int i =0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int x = r.nextInt(arr.length - i) + i;
        swap(arr,i,x);
    }
}
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    int[] arr = new int[] {1 , 5, 6, 3, 0, 11,2,9 };
    shuffle(arr, new Random());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to the following should meet your requirement.
It uses a HashSet to achieve unique elements.

```
    Set<Integer> sint = new HashSet<>();
    Random random = new Random();

    while ( sint.size() < 9){
        sint.add(random.nextInt());
    }
```

Comment: Of course one could just use the Set's size() to know when there are 9 elements in there.

Comment: @Gimby Yep. will change the example to do so.

Answer (score 0):

For you example, you can use `Collections.shuffle`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(9);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      a.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(a);
    System.out.println(a);
  }
```